# Address of the pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to understand pointers and I can't get one thing.
For instance,

```
//part of code

int *p;
int tab[3];
```

so now we have variable `tab` that contains address of first element of the array. And I want to create a pointer that points on that pointer. 
So, I would do this like this way:

```
p=&tab;
```

If it would work, `p` would be the address of `tab` (that means it would point to `tab`)
Unfortunately it doesn't work. So how to get to address of the pointer itself?
what is the correct type for address? (addresstype `*p`) I want to point of the memory block which contains address of first element of `tab`, not on `tab` itself.

Comment: Give this a read: [arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 7):

> so now we variable tab that contains address of first element of the array.

No, we have a variable `tab` which *is* an array.

> And I want to create a pointer that points on this pointer.

If you want a pointer to the first element of the array, then that's easy: an array is implicitly convertible to that pointer (which is what leads to the widespread, but incorrect belief that an array is a pointer).

```
int * p = tab;
```

If you want a pointer to the array, rather than the first element, then that's a different type:

```
int (*p)[3] = &tab;
```

But you wouldn't usually want anything like that.

> So how to get to address of pointer itself?

There is no pointer, so there's no way to get that address. If you did have a pointer, then you could take the address of that, just like any other object:

```
int * p = arr;   // Pointer to first element of array
int ** pp = &p;  // Pointer to pointer
```

> I want to point of the memory block which contains address of first element of tab, not on tab itself.

That makes no sense; `tab` *is* the memory block containing its elements.

Comment: +1 for `int (*p)[3] = tab;`, are there any situations where such a declaration would be useful?

Comment: @Paranaix: It can be useful as a function argument, so that only a correctly sized array can be passed (or the size deduced as a template parameter). You'd be more likely to use a reference rather than a pointer, though.

Comment: When i was learning about c++ it was told that tab is not an array but that's a pointer on some memory blocks(one after another).

Comment: @user3402584, Then you were unfortunately told wrong. This is a common misconception. Arrays will happily convert to pointers, but they aren't the same thing.

Comment: @user3402584: Then you were told wrong. An array is a compound object containing its elements; a pointer just holds the address of an object. Arrays are often accessed via pointers, but are not the same thing.

Comment: Hmm so it doesnt make sense for me. It works like a pointer(we do for example: *(tab+1) to gain value of tab[1] but its not a pointer?

Comment: @user3402584: An array is convertible to a pointer, as described in the answer. So `tab+1` converts it to a pointer, then adds one to get the address of `tab[1]`. But, despite allowing this conversion, the array itself is not a pointer.

Comment: hmmm,so why this wrong definition is put in cplusplus.com?

Comment: anyway ty for making it clear for me how all this process works.

Comment: @user3402584 Because cplusplus.com is a frequently wrong resource for learning C++ from. Look at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) or a book off the [Book List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1)

Comment: @user3402584 Because this misconception is so widespread, there are many people passing it on as fact. I was taught it in the nineties and it was just as wrong back then as it is now.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that arrays decays to a pointer to the first element. So whenever you need a pointer to an array, just use the array as it is. Like

```
p = tab;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int *p;
int tab[3];
p = &tab[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this code and you'll see how p points directly to the first position of the array, so you can access its values from p as well.

```
int *p;
int tab[3];

tab[0] = 56;
tab[1] = 57;
tab[2] = 58;

p = tab;

cout << p[0] <<endl;
cout << p[1] <<endl;
cout << p[2] <<endl;
```